Replace delimiter in the file
Let's take
"apple" , "tomato,potato", 100, 250, "banana" 

is my data I want replace the outer delimiter i.e. , which is same as inner delimiter. Ultimately, want my data like :
"apple" ; "tomato,potato"; 100; 250; "banana"

and the position of the string with delimeter can be anywhere in data.
I have tried many chatGPT sed commands all are not working

Do you mean you want to replace commas with semi-colons when not inside double quotes?

Bash is not appropriate to parse CSV. You need a CSV conversion tool. Maybe ask ChatGPT for a CSV conversion tool that fit your requirements. This site is for help on programming or programming tools. You will not get someone write a tool or commands to solve your CSV conversion problem. Converting CSV is not a programming question.

Use python or php or any other tool that supports CSV to read the CSV and to write  it back.

@phantom I asked Copilot for you, to show how easy it is to get an answer to your CSV conversion problem and how it is not a programming question at all. Here it is: https://copilot.microsoft.com/sl/haRpnIkMExg

Install, maybe, csvkit and try csvformat -d ',' -D ';' -bBS file.csv. Or any other CSV parser/processor.

I don't understand the downvotes. Using a CSV aware tool is better here, but @Phantom did not know. He showed his problem and what he wants, and explained that his attempts all failed. We would like to see a failing attempt, but in this case all simple sed commands fail.

Was no response good? If yes, acknowledge which one it was: it is a way of thanking the author

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed -E ':a;s/^(("[^,"]*"[^"]*)*"[^,"]*),/\1\n/;ta;y/\n,/,;/' file

First convert any commas inside double quotes to newlines.
Then transliterate newlines to commas and commas to semi-colons.
An alternate solution (kudos to Walter A):
sed -E 's/(("[^"]*"|)[^",]*),/\1;/g' file


Nice use of a label and the y/ operator (+1). However, I think it can be solved with sed easier (see my answer).

When the input has an even number of double quotes, you can match a quoted field with ("[^"]*") and the following substring until the next , with ([^",]*).
When you also want to replace delimiters between fields without quotes, add an * after the regex for a quoted field.
echo '"apple" , "tomato,potato", 100, 250, "banana" ' | sed -E 's/("[^"]*")*([^",]*),/\1\2;/g'
# or with a file
sed -E 's/("[^"]*")*([^",]*),/\1\2;/g' file

Result
"apple" ; "tomato,potato"; 100; 250; "banana"


best answer for me :) most elegant. Simple and efficient!

If a field contained an escaped double quote per the RFC 4180 standard for CSVs, that would delete part of the field. Try echo '"foo""bar""apple" , "tomato,potato", 100, 250, "banana" ' | ... and you'll see it removes "foo""bar"" from the start of first field.

@EdMorton: You are right. I don't consider the input as valid CSV. Patching my solution with | sed -E 's/""/"\r"/g; s/("[^"]*")*([^",]*),/\1\2;/g; s/"\r"/""/g' would only show that sed becomes a mess with complicated requirements, so it is restriction of this solution.
(After this patch, you could ask for a \n between the quotes, leaving me helpless).

I wouldn't normally answer a question that shows no attempt by the OP but since there are multiple answers posted already....
Your input isn't valid CSV and so YMMV trying to use a tool that understands CSV on it.
Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box you could treat the input as "-separated fields instead of ,-separated fields and replace the ,s in every odd-numbered "field":
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(/,/,";",$i)} 1' file
"apple" ; "tomato,potato"; 100; 250; "banana"

If that's not all you need then see whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk for ideas if you want to use awk for this.

Some implementations of CSV parsers may have trouble with that "sloppy" CSV. While the spaces around commas are OK, the fact that the quotes are not immediately next to the comma isn't OK. For example,

the ruby CSV module throws a MalformedCSVError "Any value after quoted field isn't allowed"
$ echo '"apple" , "tomato,potato", 100, 250, "banana"' | ruby -rcsv -e 'p CSV.parse(STDIN.readline)'
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.2/lib/ruby/3.3.0/csv/parser.rb:1066:in `parse_quotable_robust': Any value after quoted field isn't allowed in line 1. (CSV::MalformedCSVError)


python:
  $ python3
  Python 3.12.3 (main, Apr  9 2024, 08:09:14) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
  Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
  >>> import csv
  >>> line = '"apple" , "tomato,potato", 100, 250, "banana"'
  >>> for fields in csv.reader([line]):
  ...   print(fields)
  ...
  ['apple ', ' "tomato', 'potato"', ' 100', ' 250', ' "banana"']


the bash5.2 dsv module does the same thing as python: the "tomato,potato" value is not considered one field because there is a space before the opening quote, so the quotes don't have special meaning.



You can simply replace ,  with ;  using this sed command sed 's/, /; /g'.
for example:
echo '"apple" , "tomato,potato", 100, 250, "banana"' | sed 's/, /; /g'                                                                                     

output:
"apple" ; "tomato,potato"; 100; 250; "banana"


That's problematic, if any string contains a comma.

@Wiimm actually no. Only if a string contains a comma followed by a space.

Your code will change "tomato, potato" into "tomato; potato"

This is a very bad CSV, you shouldn't have the white spaces outside the double quotes.
Using Miller you can do it in this way
mlr --csvlite --ifs "," --ofs ";" -N cat input.csv >output.csv

The output
"apple" ; "tomato;potato"; 100; 250; "banana"

Some notes

--csvlite, to manage this wrong CSV format
-N, to set that CSV has no header
--ifs ",", to manage input field separator
--ofs ";", to manage output field separator


The problem here is probably that you are missing the "inplace" parameter -i.
sed -i -E 's/( *\, *)((([^,"\,])+)|("[^"]+"))/; \2/g' nameofthefile.csv 

this will substitute all occurencies of "," with ";" in the file without change them if they are inside quotes. Please  change directory to the path of the file.
If you want to do this replacement for multiple files csv in the same path use this command:
    sed -i -E 's/( *\, *)((([^,"\,])+)|("[^"]+"))/; \2/g' *.csv  


Your code will change "tomato,potato" into "tomato;potato"

I miss-read the scope. Edited the answer. It works.

It might work with the given example, but not with '3,"apple" , "tomato,potato;sausage", 100, 250, "banana" ' or 1,2,3 or 4,"!@#$%".

Sorry Walter I dind't see your answer before! It is the cleanest!
